# Dynamic dom ID created by angular NgFor is not searchable by JS

Tags: javascript, angular

I've one component where I'm creating some dynamic DIV having it's own dynamic ID(plot0, plot1) using `*ngFor` for ploting some plotly js charts. In my component.ts file I'm fetching some JSON data from an API & trying to plot those data by using one plotly service.

If you see the following line, the second parameter is the place where I'm trying to pass the dynamic DIV ID value to plotly service. In the browser's console I can see the those dynamic DIV IDs. But, somehow my JS of component.ts is can't able to see those IDs & I'm getting that `Error: No DOM element with id 'plot0' exists on the page.`

`` this.plot.plotLine("Line Plot", `plot${i}`, x, y); ``

I think it's a small issue. But can't able to fig out how to fix this. Need some expert guidance.

Here are all my codes...

**componenet.html**

```
<div class="grid grid-cols-3 gap-5 mt-10">
    <div style="border: 0px solid #ccc;" *ngFor="let trace of traces; index as i;">
        <div class="relative overflow-x-auto shadow-md sm:rounded-lg">
            <label class="text-center block  text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-white">
                <b>Metric Values</b>
            </label>                
            <div attr.id="plot{{i}}"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**componenet.ts**

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { PlotlyService } from '../plotly.service';

interface APIResponse {
data: {
    project_info: {
    assetName: string,
    id: number,
    projectName: string,
    reservoirName: string,
    },
    meta_models: [],
    traces: [{ x: number[], y: number[] }]
};
message: string;
status: boolean;
}

@Component({
    selector: 'app-home',
    templateUrl: './home.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient, private _Activatedroute: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router, private plot: PlotlyService) {
    this.apiUrl = environment.apiUrl
    }

    ngOnInit() {          
        this.get_test_traces()
    }

    apiUrl: string = ''

    traces: { x: number[], y: number[] }[] = []
    get_test_traces() {
        this.http.get<APIResponse>(`${this.apiUrl}/test`).subscribe(
        (response) => {
                console.log('response:', response)
        
                if (response['status']) {
                    this.traces = response['data']['traces']
            
                    this.traces.forEach((item, i) => {
                        let x: number[] = item.x;
                        let y: number[] = item.y;
                        console.log('x: ', x)
                        console.log('y: ', y)
            
                        this.plot.plotLine("Line Plot", `plot${i}`, x, y);
                    });
                }
            }
        )
    }
}
```

**API Response**

```
{
"data": {
    "traces": [
    {
        "x": [1,2,3,4],
        "y": [10,15,13,17]
    },
    {
        "x": [1,2,3,4],
        "y": [16,5,11,9]
    }
    ]
},
"message": "",
"status": true
}
```

**Console error**

[image]

Comment: can you create a minimally reproducible example? this is because the element is still in the virtual DOM state and has not been reflected in the real DOM yet

Comment: try `setTimeout(()=>{ this.plot.plotLine("Line Plot", \`plot${i}\`, x, y); },0)`

Comment: In the Angular onInit lifecycle hook your component has not yet rendered, so it is very likely that when your promise is resolving the compononent has yet to be rendered. This means that none of the html in your component has made it to the browser's DOM. You could try calling get_test_traces() in the lifecycle hook: ngAfterViewInit().
Also, don't bind to attr.id bind instead to id EG: `<div id="plot{{i}}"></div>`

Comment: @MordyStern ```setTimeout()``` don't looks an elegant solution but it's WORKING. :D  If you post your comment as an answer then I'll be happy to accept that. Thanks..  :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue with `plotLine` not working properly is likely due to Angular not having finished rendering the data to the DOM. A common workaround is to wrap the plotLine function call in a `setTimeout` with a delay of 0.

By using `setTimeout`, the callback function is added to the end of the event queue, which ensures that it's only executed after the elements already exist in the DOM.